# What is a good strategy/pattern for passing object properties as function parameters?

Tags: javascript

Here is what I have:

```
var url = config_ajax.url;
xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt, url){
  if (evt.lengthComputable) {
    var percent = ( evt.loaded / evt.total ) * 100;
    console.log(url);
    Pub.ajaxIndicator(percent);
  }
}, false);
```

I thought it looked bad, but JS does not like to pass config_ajax.url to the function and errors.

Comment: you don't pass anything here, you only define the argument names

Comment: That function is a callback. It gets called when the event happens with whatever parameters the event passes it. Your `url` variable isn't passed to it.

Comment: How do I pass config_ajax.url to my event handler?

Comment: actually it creates a closure and is accessible, but I wrather pass it in explicitly, but it's a callback so I don't think possible.

Comment: you can trigger a custom event in callback and pass other values

Comment: @Cognitive - that sounds kind of complex.  Does it work, have you done it?

Comment: Not tried actually but if you look at this maybe it helps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> actually it creates a closure and is accessible, but I wrather pass it in explicitly, but it's a callback so I don't think possible.

You are right. The callback is a closure and you cannot pass to it explicitly. You can only pass a value to a function when *you* are calling the function. But you are not calling the callback, it is called *for* you. You don't have any control over the URL's passed to it.

I guess you could use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set the first parameter to a specific value, if you feel that to be cleaner:

```
function showProgress(url, evt) {
  if (evt.lengthComputable) {
    var percent = ( evt.loaded / evt.total ) * 100;
    console.log(url);
    Pub.ajaxIndicator(percent);
  }
}

xhr.addEventListener("progress", showProgress.bind(null, config_ajax.url), false);
```

I recommend to get comfortable with closures, there a common and very powerful tool in JavaScript. E.g. there is no reason to create `url`, you can directly access `config_ajax` inside the callback as well.